# Удаленный доступ с помощью SSH через PuTTY

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

Я подключаюсь к серверу с помощью PuTTY через SSH. Такой вопрос, могу ли я как-то запускать файлы со своего ПК на удаленном сервере?
Или как это лучше делать?

Comment: Нет, не можешь.

Comment: Какую задачу ты хочешь решить?

Comment: Закачать на сервер через тот же SSH да запустить, не?

Comment: @AlexeyTen , задача в том ,чтобы запустить написанную прогу на с++ на сервере

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы используете PuTTY, могу предположить, что у Вас на локальной машине установлен Windows, а на удаленной Linux или FreeBSD. Две последние ОС не имеют встроенной возможности запуска программ, написанных под Windows (exe файлы).

Самым простым способом (но не самым надежным) будет скопировать программу на удаленный компьютер с помощью протокола SFTP и запустить ее с помощью эмулятора Wine.

Если у Вас на локальной машине Linux, для переноса файла попробуйте воспользоваться стандартной утилитой sftp. Ее можно запустить из командной строки следующим образом:

```
sftp user_name@host.name
```

Для записи файла на удаленный сервер используйте команду

```
put filename
```

Вы так же можете попробовать подключить удаленную файловую систему с помощью утилиты sshfs и работать с файлами как будто они физически находятся на локальной машине.

Помимо sshfs есть и другие протоколы для подключения удаленных файловых систем, возможно в Вашем случае подойдет другой протокол.